# Can I auto-import a namespace in MS Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

When developing for Android in Eclipse, for example, it's easy to automatically import packages and classes by hitting Ctrl+Shift+O. I'm finding it difficult to write code every time I have to go google a function to figure out its namespace ... is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `Ctrl + Shift + F10` or `Ctrl+` shortcut, that provides some light refactorings like creating method stubs, renames methods and variables and imports usings.
This shortcut is not always available - it can be used when a small red box underneath, after you click it you'll see the drop-down menu with a choice of possible actions

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, this wasn't the case when I first posted this question. I did not have references to the libraries that were being used, so it gave me no options except an error. Now that I've added references, I get these cues.

Comment: @pharaoh much depends on the sortcuts settings in your environment/

Answer (score 2):

Once you've added a dll as a reference, VS will suggest this as part of its intellisense feature.  Type in the name, and then hover over it - there will be a blue (maybe it is red?) underline - and VS will give you an arrow to click that lets you add the namespace.

If it is a namespace you find yourself adding frequently, you can add it to your config so that you're not doing it in files across your project.

(I do have Resharper installed so I can't check this, but I'm pretty sure VS has this natively...)

Answer (score 0):

When you type in a class name, hit Ctrl + . a list would appear, then hit Enter on what you need